# Give group of users install privilages in R but not affect root install?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions

So we have a few users who use a number of servers for various computations.  They constantly ask us to install packages from bioconductor and cran for R.  It's a real bother and truthfully they can be trusted to do it themselves.

We would like to offload this responsibility onto them and allow them to install packages themselves. How can we go about setting this up so their newly packages go into a separate location that doesn't affect the mainline install.  It's Ubuntu 14.04 as the OS.